# What is the difference between "echo $PATH" and /etc/paths?

Tags: osx, path

When I echo $PATH I get this: `Users/myusername/.node_modules_global/bin:/Users/mac/.node_modules_global/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/platform-tools`.

I want to remove some paths from this, but when I open the file using the command `vim /etc/paths`, I get the following results:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Is the file /etc/paths different from the $PATH variable?

Comment: Which version of OS X? I don't have `/etc/paths` in mine, but I'm running `10.4.11` and things have probably changed since then

Comment: But according to [an answer on AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/135346), `/etc/paths` is used to generate the default `$PATH`, which you can later modify

Comment: It's the default. By the time user starts their shell, though, it would be modified by other files that shell sources, like `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`

Answer (score 20):

`/etc/paths` is part of what's used to set up `$PATH` for shell processes. When you open a new Terminal window, it starts `bash`, which runs several startup scripts: `/etc/profile` AND `~/.bash_profile` OR (if that doesn't exist) `~/.bash_login` OR (if that doesn't exist either) `~/.profile`. These scripts set up the shell environment, including `$PATH`.

One of the things `/etc/profile` does is run `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, which reads `/etc/paths` and any files in `/etc/paths.d`, and adds their contents to `$PATH`. But this is just a starting point; your own startup script (if any exist) can add to `$PATH`, edit it, replace it completely, etc.

It looks to me like your startup script (and/or things it runs) is adding a number of entries to the basic set it gets from `/etc/paths`. "Users/myusername/.node_modules_global/bin:/Users/mac/.node_modules_global/bin:" is added to the beginning of `$PATH` (meaning those directories will be searched first), and ":/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/platform-tools" is added at the end. If you want to know exactly what's adding them, you need to look at your startup script.

BTW, this process for setting up `$PATH` only applies to bash "login" shells. Anything run by a bash shell will inherit `$PATH` from it, so probably have essentially the same thing. bash non-login shells follow a somewhat different setup process. Other shells, and things not started from a shell at all (e.g. cron jobs) may have completely different `$PATHs`.

Comment: Note that for non-login shells (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/bash` as installed by `brew`, without the `-l` argument), `/usr/libexec/path_helper` is not used, and `/usr/local/bin` is not included by default in the `$PATH`. To use `path_helper` in a script or interactively, the command is `eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper)`.

Answer (score 0):

First places I'd look to check for modifications are,

```
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
```

If you're using something that's not Bash, check the configuration files for it to see any mention of PATH.